# Auto-Populate the User Field in Django (no such column)

Tags: python, django, forms, admin, auto-populate

I am attempting to auto-populate the 'pub_date' field in my BucketListItemForm.  I have been able to do this with the time and date field but continually get the following error when trying to do this with the 'pub_by' field:

no such column: BucketList_bucketlistitem.pub_by_id

I have been playing around with everything I can think of and looking at other people with similar problems posted on StackOverflow over the past few days but nothing seems to be solving my problem.  I would greatly appreciate any amount of help you could offer!

forms.py

```
class BucketListItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = BucketListItem
```

models.py

```
class BucketListItem(models.Model):
text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
pub_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.text

def recently_added(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

recently_added.boolean = True

def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.pub_date = timezone.now()
    super(BucketListItem, self).save()
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    all_list_items = BucketListItem.objects.all()
    context = {'all_list_items': all_list_items}
    return render(request, 'BucketList/index.html', context)

def my_list(request):
    personal_list = BucketListItem.objects.filter(pub_by = request.user.username)
    context = {'personal_list': personal_list,
                  'user': request.user.username}
    return render(request, 'BucketList/mylist.html', context)

def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = BucketListItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/bucketlist/mylist')
    else:
        form = BucketListItemForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('BucketList/create_item.html', args)
```

admin.py

```
class BucketListItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Text',              {'fields': ['text']}),
    ]
    readonly_fields = ('pub_date',)
    list_display = ['text', 'pub_date', 'pub_by', 'recently_added']
    list_filter = ['pub_date', 'pub_by']
    search_fields = ['text']

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change:
        obj.user = request.user
    super(self.__class__, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(BucketListItem, BucketListItemAdmin)
```

mylist.html

```
{% if user %}

<h1>{{user}}'s Bucket List</h1>
{% if personal_list %}
    <ol>
    {% for item in personal_list %}
        <li>{{ item.text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have any Bucket List items yet!  Better get on that.</p>
{% endif %}

{% else %}
    <p>Sorry, it doesn't seem like you are logged in!</p>
{% endif %}
```

create_item.html

```
<form action = "/bucketlist/create/" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Create BucketListItem">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to sync the database after updating your code. Try deleting the database you're using (or dropping it) and run `syncdb` again. I could help you further if you post your complete code ie html files with the forms rendered if this does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I followed your advise and now everything is working except for the mylist view stated above in the error message:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Mike'(with 'Mike' being my current logged in account)

Comment: Along with that the 'create' view produces a drop down list for the 'pub_by' field rather than automatically passing the username through to the form.  If you have any advise on this as well I would be unbelievably grateful!

Comment: Np. Glad I could help. You will have to change the form definition for that to happen. You will also need to pass in the user to the form or exclude it and add it when saving the form.

The other is a python error: you are trying to pass an `int` from a `string` with no interger val. e.g. `int('word')`

Comment: I got everything all figured out!  Thank you so much for your help.